# Как посчитать сколько раз вызвана функция с помощью декоратора

Tags: python

Как в декораторе можно хранить переменную, которая показывала бы сколько раз вызывали данную функцию? Первое что пришло в голову - заюзать вместе декоратор с замыканиями, но дальше идеи ничего не пришло в голову.

```
def decor(func):
    def wrapper():
        i=0
        func()
        i+=1
        print(f'{i}')
    return wrapper

@decor
def test():
    pass

test()
test()
test()
```

Comment: [Пример от создателей Python](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/functools.py#L567) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Вынести переменную-счётчик в сам декоратор:

```
def decor(func):
    i=0
    def wrapper():
        nonlocal i
        func()
        i+=1
        print(f'{i}')
    return wrapper
```

Тогда печатает так:

```
1
2
3
```